# How to load a JSF 2.0 composite component via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have designed a composite component that looks something like this:

```
 <cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="title" required="true" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <div class="inputTile">
        <div class="inputTitle">
            <span>#{cc.attrs.title}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputTileContent">
            <input type="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
        </div>

    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

I am trying to load this onto a div on my web page through AJAX.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "load this onto a div"?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo" layout="block">
    <your:composite rendered="#{bean.loadCompositeInDiv}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton value="Load composite in div" action="#{bean.setLoadCompositeInDiv(true)}">
    <f:ajax render="foo" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped 
public class Bean {

    private boolean loadCompositeInDiv;

    // Getter+setter
}
```